# Opening pdf file

Tags: python

I wanna open pdf file from python console, I can do it with `os.system(filename)`, it will open in adobe reader, but the problem is that `os.system` also opens a command prompt, is there another way that won't open command prompt?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([file],shell=True)
```

Comment: Since the file is not executable is might not always work ("permission denied"), you might want to use the solution I found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87597/problem-with-subprocess-popen-permission-denied#comment138914_87597) (`subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])`)

Comment: Thank you David for this pointer to subprocess.call. This was the solution I needed to start up via the file type.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Just one doubt why do we need shell argument as True here?

Answer (score 26):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(r'file://C:\path\to\file.pdf')
```

Answer (score 18):

```
import os
os.startfile(filename)
```

Comment: This works only in Windows. (`startfile` is not available in Linux)

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows, just kind of crashes the application. However, the solution using subprocess did work. Thanks

Answer (score -7):

This is a bit late but nobody mentioned:

```
open("file_name.pdf")
```

Comment: The reason that no one mentioned that is because it is not what OP wanted. That will open the file internally in Python to be edited etc. It will not open the file in a program such as Adobe Acrobat, which is what they wanted.

Comment: True. The question is not the one I answered.

Comment: Then why is this not deleted?

Comment: I mean it was a different question when I answered it.