# Preferred Method of Opening a PDF in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Is there a newer way to open a PDF using an external viewer from Python 3 in Linux other than `subprocess`?

This sounds like a noobish and duplicate question, but I looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679798/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-standard-application) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453338/opening-pdf-file), and all of the answers are over 7 years old and recommended discouraged methods like `os.system`, old methods like manually creating a `subprocess.Popen` or Windows-only methods like `os.startfile`.

So in the time since these questions were answered, have preferred methods of launching a PDF reader from within Python emerged, or are these still the best answers?

Comment: I will suggest using this guide that I followed a while back https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-pdf-documents-using-python--cms-25726

Comment: @theBrainyGeek thanks, clarified my question. I'm looking for something that will open an external viewer, like Evince

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/435669/399317

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python)

Comment: So: nope, these are still the best answers, windows still provides a system call accessible as `os.startfile`, linux still provides a command line tool `xdg-open` and mac still provides `open`, you still need to use subprocess with these, and [there's still no standard Python utility](https://bugs.python.org/issue3177) to choose the correct tool for your particular OS.

Comment: @Kos thanks, your comment answers my question. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python as of 3.6 still doesn't have a cross-platform way to open files using default programs.
[Issue 3177](https://bugs.python.org/issue3177) suggested to add one, but it didn't happen yet.

So:

- On Windows, there's a system call for this, you can reach it from Python via [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile),
- On Linux, there's a command-line tool called [`xdg-open`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) that does this,
- On Mac OS, there's a command-line tool simply called `open`.

This means that unfortunately you still need to check the operating system and pick the right approach. The correct way to call the command-line tools is using the `subprocess` module.

This answer provides a code snippet:

[Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python/435669#435669)