# How to open file pdf in click button reportlab python

Tags: python, reportlab

Please I need to open file pdf in navigateur from one click reportlab python
thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add your code here, what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import os

os.startfile(namefile.pdf)

####################

If you need other answers :

[Opening pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453338/opening-pdf-file)