# Open and save a PDF file using Acrobat Reader in the background using Python

Tags: python, pdf, acrobat, pywinauto, hebrew

Following the [Opening pdf file question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453338/opening-pdf-file)

**I am looking for a way to also command Adobe Acrobat Reader to save the file programmatically using Python.**

I am not looking for the [pikepdf](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf) way of saving the file.

**Reason**: [This PDF file](https://github.com/inathan99/PDF/raw/main/Total.pdf), created with [fill-pdf](https://github.com/t-houssian/fillpdf), needs to go through special formatting done by Acrobat Reader upon opening. Upon exit Acrobat Reader asks whether to save the formatting it did, I need this "Yes, Save" to be via code.

**Edit**: How to proceed from here using pywinauto?

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

pdf_file = r'C:\Path\To\Total.pdf'
acrobat_path = r"C:\Path\To\Acrobat.exe"

app = Application(backend=u'uia').start(cmd_line = acrobat_path + ' ' + pdf_file)
print("started")
time.sleep(1)
app = Application(backend=u'uia').connect(path=acrobat_path)
print("connected")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution with pyautogui:**

```
import os
os.startfile(path)
filename = os.path.basename(path)
focus = pg.getWindowsWithTitle(filename)
while len(focus) == 0:
    focus = pg.getWindowsWithTitle(filename)
focus [0].show() # show() for python3.9, activate() for python3.7
time.sleep(1)
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(1)
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'q')
print("Blessed Be God")
```